How do I know whether I need to clear security during an international transfer?
On some international-to-international connections, you need to clear security on others you do not. Examples: coming from the US you go through security in London Heathrow, Paris CDG or Doha but not in Frankfurt, Zurich or Tokyo.
The basic rule here is: "You need to clear transfer security unless the airport has a waiver for your departure country". But so far I have found no reliable information on what waivers are in place at which airport. Which brings me to my question

How do I find out whether I need to pass through transfer security for a specific route or not?

Transfer security is a major hassle: You often have to hike a fairly long way through the catacombs to the check point and then back again to the departure gate. Lines are often be long and slow, so I like to avoid it as much as possible.
This was triggered by Is one hour enough for international transfer in Brisbane?: where the answer I think would be "1 hour is typically just fine unless you have to go through transit security".

Even if you normally do not need to go through security, there are situations where/when you still have to, like an incoming gate change, a report of something happening on your departure airport or a change in policy.

FYI: Which countries force all arriving international passengers to claim their luggage for the purpose of customs inspection, even if passengers have one more leg in their trip?

I’m pretty sure there was a very similar question in the last year or two but can’t find it. I don’t think there’s any easy way to find out, and the rules can be complex (in some cases for the same origin/connecting airport pair, it may vary on the airline used!). In may also depend on the destination country (e.g. US or Israel). Transit security is also organised very differently in different airports: some have small transfer checkpoints all over the airport (e.g. HKG), others do make you walk quite a bit (e.g. CDG gates L and M at least, where you’ll use the departures checkpoint).

@jcaron Maybe you're referring to Which airport has the longest minimum connection time?

@FranckDernoncourt no, it was a question very close to this one, about in which cases does one need to go through security again or not. Or at least the answers were. Maybe it was https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/180040/security-after-landing-in-frankfurt-airport/180042 (which explains a number of rules, which sadly are not consistently applied).

@FranckDernoncourt There’s probably another one, I remember something about some flights from Narita allowed to bypass security (in some European airport, Frankfurt I think) and not others (depending on the airline) as an illustration of the complexity.

@jcaron Got it, I wondered whether I asked a similar question and whether it got deleted (as a list question). Feature request: Add users' deleted questions in search results.

@jcaron Was it When does Narita do security screening for international transit passengers??

@TripeHound Mmhh… I remembered it the other way around but I may be wrong. But it does show that it’s indeed difficult to determine when you may have to go through security or not, given the number of parameters.

I did ask a question once about the "why". But since the decision is more or less random (FRA trust the TSA, LHR doesn't), there is no way to infer it so this question is specifically about getting the information.

Similar question about International-to-domestic connections in Canada, though it got closed:  https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/175102/4171
